# Need programmatic method to detect has_many and has_one relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I want to be able to detect the presence of the set of [has_one, has_many, belongs_to] relationships on an ActiveRecord model object.  Stated another way, I want to be able to detect from ruby code in the model whether it has one of the above relationships defined.

Is there some clever way, other than the brute force searching of model attributes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at Rails' [ActiveRecord::Reflection methods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html) to get what you're looking for.

`Model.reflections` will return a hash of that model's associations keyed with the association name.  `Model.reflect_on_all_associations` will return an array of those associations, leaving out the named keys.

So, you can do something like this:

```
Post.reflections.keys  # => [:comments, :author]
Post.reflections[:comments].marco  # => :has_many
Post.reflections[:author].macro    # => :belongs_to
# etc etc
```

Take a look at the data that is returned from these methods and you should be able to figure out how to do what you want.